# Application version or milestone Naming Schemes

Tags: naming-conventions, version, milestone

### **I'm looking for "schemes" for application version or milestone naming**.

I'd like to find a naming scheme that suits my current project but I think we should gather here the more interesting schemes to share knowledge and ideas on the subject.

**You also should provide the number of possible name with the proposed scheme or an estimate.**

For example :

- **[OGRE (Object-Oriented-Graphic-Rendering-Engine)](http://www.ogre3d.org/)** : [each version](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/Roadmap) is named like one of "[The Great Old Ones"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Old_One) from [Lovecraft's "The Call of Cthulhu" mythos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu) - 67 possible names.
- **[Ubuntu (Linux based OS)](http://www.ubuntu.com/)** :  [as explained here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames)

> The development codename of a release
>   takes the form "Adjective Animal". So
>   for example: Warty Warthog (Ubuntu
>   4.10), Hoary Hedgehog (Ubuntu 5.04), Breezy Badger (Ubuntu 5.10), are the
>   first three releases of Ubuntu. In
>   general, people refer to the release
>   using the adjective, like "warty" or
>   "breezy".

That allow a finite but very big possible name count.

- Some hardware and software releases are named like **real world big cities** - hundreds of possible names;
- Some hardware and software releases are named like **(Greek-Roman-whatever) mythology gods or king/warlord/emperor** - tenths of possible names my mythology;
- etc.

For my own project I'm thinking about using a naming scheme that would be to name public releases like popular software principles/philosophies/rules/pattern like DRY, KISS, YAGNI, Singleton, Factory, Visitor, etc.
But it feel maybe a little too much...computer-geek. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with programming terms as project names is that they're confusing for most users. They'd make great internal codenames.

I've heard major rivers used as project names - Nile, Brisbane, etc.

check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rivers

Releasing in alphabetical order helps users remember which version is more recent.

Comment: Having internal code names and separate public release names is interesting, thanks for the suggestion! Now that I think about it, computer software development popular principles and patterns could be confusing in the devs team chats...

Answer (score 5):

I personally find naming release versions of a software product after mythological creatures, furry animals and geographic landmarks all just a bit new age and pretentious. Fine for a beta or internal working codename maybe, but there's no substitute for proper version numbers when releasing to your end users.

Just my 2c
Kev

Answer (score 2):

We used to use all the different names from hell and its mythology.  Our production server was my favorite: Horus.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [collective noun](http://www.ojohaven.com/collectives/) pairs (apostrophes left out deliberately):

aardvarks armoury

blacksmiths anvil

crow murder

tanks clank

snipe wisp

Answer (score 1):

frankly i don't get Ubuntu's release naming scheme - too many names thrown at us too often. Windows can get way with XP and Vista every now and then (every 3-4 years?) but Ubuntu is too aggressive with hodgepodge of names every 6 mos.

to answer your question - what's wrong with good old 8.10 and 9.04? KISS indeed

Comment: The version number scheme is not a problem and is already set. The problem is more to give "human-friendly" names to my software's public releases (one for several versions numbers), for easier user feedback (the name is displayed in big chars inside the application) and subtle marketing purposes...

Comment: e.g. like Apple's OS scheme - 10.4 = Tiger, 10.5 = Leopard etc. You can use either name and most people are familiar with both

Comment: after a while these names do not mean much - was "Mouse" before the "Elephant"? or the other way? whereas 10.4 and 10.5 leave no ambiguity